# Excel Add-In Doesn't work after protecting in the VBA Editor

Tags: excel, add-in

I have written and compiled an XLA - Excel Add-In. The problem with the add-in is that if I password protect the ADD-In Project file, the macro I have written doesn't show up in  . If the xla  vbaproject is unprotected the macro do appear in excel option > customize > macro.

Please help me with it explaining easy way to protect my code with add-in.